# Maximum Total Surface Area due to hole in sphere.

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima

*Question*
[image: Question image format]

**My attempt**
[image: rough view]
The region between the dotted lines shows the hollow region.

The distance MP = $ \sqrt{R^2 - x^2} $
Hollow area created = 2πx×2MP
= $4πx\sqrt{R^2- x^2}$

The area removed due to hole = 2×(area of the cap )

What I did is I calculated solid angle $\Omega$ = ${ πx^2\over {R^2 -x^2}}$

And I took the curved surface area of each cap to be ${ \Omega × 4πR^2\over 4π}$ = $\Omega R^2$ = ${ πx^2R^2\over {R^2 -x^2}}$

So, New Total Surface Area

(TSA) = 4π$R^2$ - 2×area of each cap + hollow area

= 4π$R^2$ - 2×${ πx^2R^2\over {R^2 -x^2}}$ + 4πx$\sqrt{R^2- x^2}$

For this to be maximum, I differentiated  this and equated to 0 and after removing denomiator I got

$R^2x^2$ + 2${(R^2 - x^2)}^{5/2}$
=   2$R^2x(R^2 - x^2)$ + 2$x^2(R^2 - x^2)^{3/2}$

Which I am unable to solve further.

Any help , hint or solution would be appreciated. Also I want to know whether my expression of TSA is right.

Comment: Can you please provide me some key idea for solving this or a new approach?

Comment: I don't understand your calculus of the solid angle. Why you don't use the hint in the problem?

Comment: The expression for solid angle should be $ \ \Omega \ = \ 2 \pi · (\cos \lambda_{upper} \ - \ \cos \lambda_{lower}) \ \ , \ $ with the $ \ \lambda \ $ representing latitude on the (angular) sphere.  We have $$   \lambda_{upper} \ \ = \ \ \arccos \left(\frac{h/2}{R} \right) \ \ = \ \  \arccos \left( \frac{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}{R} \right) \ \ \ \ \text{and}  \ \ \ \ \lambda_{lower} \ \ = \ \ \arccos \left(\frac{-h/2}{R} \right) , \ $$ which is then in agreement with the area given in the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the given hint. The surface area of a segment of height $h$ on a sphere of radius $R$ is $2 \pi R h$. Here $h = R - \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$. There are two such segments removed by drilling the hole.

So surface area removed from the sphere: $4 \pi R^2 - 4 \pi R \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$

Surface area of the sphere remaining: $4 \pi R \sqrt{R^2 -x^2}$

Surface area of the cylindrical surface through the sphere: $2 \pi x \cdot 2 \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$

Total surface $S = 4 \pi R \sqrt{R^2 -x^2} + 4 \pi x  \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$

$S = 4 \pi (R + x) \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$

$ \displaystyle \frac{dS}{dx} = \frac{4 \pi (R^2 - R x - 2x^2)}{\sqrt{R^2- x^2}}$

Solving $R^2 - R x - 2x^2 = 0$, we find that $S$ is maximized when $x = R/2$.

Comment: I could not get that the hint was for the cap. Thanks a lot for detailed solution.